# Invalid column issue

Tags: sql, join, view

I created a view as below from my existing tables:

```
Create View LostCase
As 
    Select L.LNO,Count(*) "NoOfCasesLost"
    From L, LWCS,C
    Where L.LNO=LWCS.LNO
      And LWCS.CASENO=C.CNO
      And C.OUTCOME='LOSE'
    Group By L.LNO ;
```

However, whenever I run query as per below , I always get

> invalid column name for LostCase.NoOfCasesLost

```
Select L.LNO,L.LNAME,LostCase.NoOfCasesLost
From L, LostCase
Where L.LNO = LostCase.LNO;
```

I don't get it why it happens.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have specified the column name in the quotation marks, you have to refer it afterwards as:

```
 Select L.LNO,L.LNAME,LostCase."NoOfCasesLost"
 From L,LostCase
 Where L.LNO=LostCase.LNO;
```